# What is the correct use of .choices when using keys?

Tags: latex3, l3keys

I try to create a key `normanius` in the following way: Each key is mapped to an own variable `\l__normanius_*_tl` so that I can use those variables in some subsequent code.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { normanius }
 {
   one .bool_set:N = \l__normanius_one_bool,
   one .initial:n = { false },
   
   two .tl_set:N = \l__normanius_two_tl,
   two .initial:n = { anything },
   
   three .tl_set:N = \l__normanius_three_tl,
   three .initial:n = { foo },
   three .choices:nn = { foo, bar } { }

 }
 
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m}{
  \keys_set:nn { normanius }{ #1 }
  \bool_if:NTF\l__normanius_one_bool
   { (yes,~\l__normanius_two_tl,~\l__normanius_three_tl) }
   { (no,~\l__normanius_two_tl,~\l__normanius_three_tl) } 
  
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\test{}

\test{one=true, three=bar}    % No error, but choice is not set
%\test{one=true, three=ohoh}  % Error, choice is checked
\end{document}
```

The above creates this output:

```
(no, anything, foo)
(yes, anything, foo)
```

However, it should be `(yes, anything, bar)` in the second line. The choice is checked, `\test{one=true, three=ohoh}` would issue an error. However, `l__normanius_three_tl` is never updated.

What do I get wrong here? Why is `l__normanius_three_tl` not set properly?

Comment: The second argument in the choice is empty, so your key is doing nothing. Check the example in interface3.pdf

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I saw the example, but I thought the code block was meant for other uses, like error handling. So you would use something like `\tl_set:Nn \l__normanius_three_tl {\l_keys_choice_tl}`? So it does not make sense to use `.tl_set` in combination with `.choices`?

Comment: yes quite right.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It's a bit counterintuitive that `.tl_set` is not working here, and that I have to use `\tl_set:Nn` myself each time I use `.choices`. Not a bad thing if this was mentioned in the docs somehow... :)

Comment: Just noticed that `three .tl_set:N = \l__normanius_three_tl` is required, otherwise the variable `\l__normanius_three_tl` is unknown in the code block of `.choices`... This behavior is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: I would generally predeclare variables with \tl_new:N outside the \keys_define.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I noticed that using `\l_keys_choice_tl` is problematic if there are multiple choice-keys in the same key set: The latter invocation will override earlier calls of `\l_keys_choice_tl`... Am I using keys totally wrong here?

Comment: sorry I didn't look carefully at your comment. Why don't you use `\tl_set:Nn\l__normanious_three_tl{#1}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ...because I don't know how things work :) Thank you, you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestions from the discussion above, I found a working solution. The sample code below illustrates how one could use keys with choices.

It is important to use groups here, otherwise the initialization of the keys does not work properly.

An important resource is the interface document of LaTeX3 / l3kernel, see [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}


\ExplSyntaxOn
% Declare variables. Not exactly needed in this example, 
% but recommended.
\bool_new:N \l__normanius_one_bool
\tl_new:N \l__normanius_two_bool
\tl_new:N \l__normanius_three_bool
\tl_new:N \l__normanius_four_bool

% Define keys with accessor variables, and default settings.
\keys_define:nn { normanius }
 {
   one .bool_set:N = \l__normanius_one_bool,
   one .initial:n = { false },
   
   two .tl_set:N = \l__normanius_two_tl,
   two .initial:n = { anything },
   
   three .tl_set:N = \l__normanius_three_tl,
   three .initial:n = { foo },
   three .choices:nn = { foo, bar } { \tl_set:Nn \l__normanius_three_tl {#1} },
   
   four .tl_set:N = \l__normanius_four_tl,
   four .initial:n = { A1 },
   four .choices:nn = { A1, A2, A3 } { \tl_set:Nn \l__normanius_four_tl {#1} },
 }
 
% Some function that makes use of the keys.
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m}{
  % Use groups to ensure local assignments. Ensures that the default 
  % values are reinitialized each time this command is called!
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { normanius }{ #1 }
  \bool_if:NTF\l__normanius_one_bool
   { (yes,~\l__normanius_two_tl,~\l__normanius_three_tl,~\l__normanius_four_tl) }
   { (no,~\l__normanius_two_tl,~\l__normanius_three_tl,~\l__normanius_four_tl) } 
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\noindent
\test{}\\
\test{one=true, three=bar}\\
\test{one=true, three=bar}\\
\test{three=bar, three=foo}\\
\test{three=bar, four=A2}\\
%\test{one=true, three=ohoh}  % Error! 
\end{document}
```

This creates the following output:

```
(no, anything, foo, A1)
(yes, anything, bar, A1)
(yes, anything, bar, A1)
(no, anything, foo, A1)
(no, something, foo, A1)
(no, anything, bar, A2)
```